# SQL Server query to create a new column for each date within a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a program that has the user select a date range then it querys  a SQL server database to retrieve the dates they worked with the hours. I want to have the dates in their own columns instead of all in the same one. For example:

```
Employee   Total Hours  Monday 3/10  Tuesday 3/11 ....
Doe, John    40             8             8
```

Here's the query right now:

```
SELECT e.emp_fullname, t.tc_hours, t.punchDate 
FROM WaspTime.dbo.vEmployeeInfo as e, WaspTime.dbo.vTimeCards as t 
WHERE e.emp_id = t.tc_emp 
AND t.punchDate >= '03/10/2013'
AND t.punchDate <= '03/20/2013'
```

And this is the result:

```
Smith, Dan  8  2013-03-10 00:00:00.000
Smith, Dan  8 2013-03-11 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Do you have a table of dates or is it just based on dates that are available?

Comment: What is the source data structure?  We'd just be guessing based on your existing query.

Comment: do a google search on "sql server pivot query"

Comment: you can also achieve this with Dsql, though the pivot solution may be better.

Comment: TimeCards has the employee id, every date, and the hours they worked that day.

Comment: I'd be looking to do the final pivot in Excel instead of the DB, where it is much easier to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, repeated for however many periods you have.

I'm assuming you'd:

- need to `SUM` (or `COUNT?`) your hours?
- use some kind of `@period_start_date` parameter that each of the periods are then offset by a day, 2 days, 3 days, etc...

Done by hand in text editor so please forgive typos, or if the thing just plain doesn't work - but I think the idea is clear/sound.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetHoursWorkedInPeriod @periodStartDate datetime = getdate() AS
SELECT 
e.emp_fullname, 
sum(t1.tc_hours) as 'Day1Hours', 
min(t1.punchDate) as 'Day1Date'.

sum(t2.tc_hours) as 'Day2Hours', 
min(t2.punchDate) as 'Day2Date',

sum(t3.tc_hours) as 'Day3Hours', 
min(t3.punchDate) as 'Day3Date',

...and so on

FROM 
WaspTime.dbo.vEmployeeInfo as e

inner join WaspTime.dbo.vTimeCards as t1
on e.emp_id = t1.tc_emp 
AND t1.punchDate >= DATEADD (day , 0 , @periodStartDate )
AND t1.punchDate < DATEADD (day , 1 , @periodStartDate )

inner join WaspTime.dbo.vTimeCards as t2
on e.emp_id = t2.tc_emp 
AND t2.punchDate >= DATEADD (day , 1 , @periodStartDate )
AND t2.punchDate < DATEADD (day , 2 , @periodStartDate )

inner join WaspTime.dbo.vTimeCards as t3
on e.emp_id = t3.tc_emp 
AND t3.punchDate >= DATEADD (day , 2 , @periodStartDate )
AND t3.punchDate < DATEADD (day , 3 , @periodStartDate )

...and so on.

GROUP BY
e.emp_fullname
```

Edited to limit each period to a day as requested by OP, and also explicitly include the date to which the hours apply in the result set.

Comment: So then would I have to create a join for each day that I wanted to have? Is there a way that I could do it dynamically? The time span will usually be two weeks, but I want it to be a little more flexible than that.

Comment: @Nicknack1016 Using this approach (I've just updated this to be an SP), you'd just need to once-off do a cut/paste of the repeating bits and update the offsets eg 14 times (or say 31 to cover a month) to complete the SP implementation.  Then your code that consumes this SP specifies the period start date, and then dynamically selects only the `"Day" + dayNumber + "Hours"` and  `"Day" + dayNumber + "Date"` columns that it's interested in.  Or even better don't use `DayXHours` and `DayXDate` in the SP, use `HoursX` and `DateX` so you can select on `"Hours" + dayNumber` and `"Date"  + dayNumber`

Comment: @Nicknack1016 Thanks for the accept, I really appreciate it.  I'm interested to know if you're actually going ahead with this solution or not?  If so - more than happy to keep helping with it if it's not quite right (as long as we stay under the existing scope of your question).

Comment: No problem =) it really did help. I am using it, but I'm trying to tweak it in a way that would find the day of the week given a date, i.e. Monday given 3/11/13, and put that as the column header instead of "Day1Hours". Once I get that, and a total hours column, everything should be perfect.

Comment: @Nicknack1016 To get day names, use `datename(dw, t1.punchdate)`. If you need this as the column heading in SQL, you'd need to build a dynamic SQL string with these values injected/concatenated in as column aliases. But if this query is used by reporting services or some other programmatic client, then just passing those day names back as part of your select list should make them available for use as headers. Total hours, as in total for the period? `Sum(t1.hours) + sum(t2.hours) + .. + sum(tN.hours) as TotalHours`. Let me know if you'd like the answer updated to generate the SQL dynamically.

Comment: I'm now doing the column headings through the c#, as well as a few other things. It's almost perfect, but the one problem I'm having is that when there isn't any data in vTimeCards, it doesn't create a row for it. For example, if I do 3/11 - 3/17, three employees come up and when I do 4/1 - 4/5, eleven employees come up. When I do 3/11 - 4/5, the first three show, but not the other eight. I have a feeling it's a problem with the joins, but I'm not sure where exactly. Here's my query, it's not this exact situation, but it's just in case you wanted to see it http://pastebin.com/sybryWmS

Comment: I think I figured it out. I'm using a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of the inner. It works fine, but the query takes over a minute to execute. That's for about three weeks though. I think the maximum this will be used for is two weeks. Is there a way I could speed it up, or is this just an effect of having so much data to retrieve?

Comment: @Nicknack1016 Re performance,  You could try moving the date filtering expressions from each of the joins, into a where clause (leaving just the ID comparison in the join). This _might_ mean the DBMS is free to do all the joins really quickly without having to do the row by row date range check every time, and then it can just apply the range checks for each column during one final iteration of the resultset's rows. Not sure it'll make a difference, but worth exploring. Failing that, post a new Q asking how to optimize your otherwise working SQL query?

Comment: @Nicknack1016 re joins... Yes sorry, inner joins will exclude results if one of the joins fails to find a row